# Which are the conventions of typesetting a vector variable denoted by a Greek letter?

Tags: greek, italic, vector

I have noticed that there are several ways to denote that a variable represent a vector, an arrow above, a tilde underneath, and typesetting the variable in bold non-italic font. I started using the latter, but ran into issues with Greek letters. I finally found a solution in the upgreek package, but the fact that this was not available in the default font makes me wonder if I am using a non-standard way to typeset vector variables.

Is there a preferred way of typesetting vector variables when they are denoted by Greek characters? Should they be upright and bold? Or upright, italicized and bold?

Comment: At the very least, specify your context. Mathematicians for example care not a jot whether your variable is a scalar or a vector, and would not ever imagine adorning the symbol or changing the font just because it is a vector. Physicists and engineers likely disagree.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for the comment, I just started a machine learning course online and I am taking notes using markdown and latex. The prof in that class uses the same variable for vectors as for anything else, but he enforces the notation verbally ("..let beta be a vector of..."). As I read a bit online, I saw that there were several recommendations for vector variable notation, so I am curious if there is one style that is generally preferred (maybe an ISO recommendation or something similar).

Comment: There is an [ISO recommendation](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=31887); I refuse on principle to pay 150+ CHF to have someone dictate to me how to write my mathematics.

Comment: Note that, if you're not stuck to the default Computer Modern, there are quite a few fonts that offer the choice between upright or slanted for Greek Letters: `fourier`, `kpfonts`, `Minion Pro`, `newpx` or `newtx`.

Comment: @WillieWong -- besides being pricey, the iso recommendation was created by engineers and physicists, not by mathematicians, and some of the specified notation is *not* the accepted "mathematical way".  (cf. disagreement regarding the differential *d*.)

Comment: Quoth [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_notation) -- or rather a contributor who (presumably) had access to the ISO recommendation referenced by @WillieWong -- ISO "recommends either bold italic serif [...] or non-bold italic serif accented by a right arrow". In either case (assuming that it holds true for Greek too) that obviates the need for upright Greek letters.